# Why isn't req.query functioning as expected in NEXT.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, router, next.js13

I have the following code in the latest NextJS App Router, inside the file `app\api\products\route.tsx`

```js
import { initMongoose } from "@/lib/mongoose";
import Product from "@/models/products";
import { NextApiRequest } from "next";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req: NextApiRequest,res: NextResponse) {
  await initMongoose();
  console.log("Query is ",req.query);
  return NextResponse.json( await Product.find().exec() )
}
```

However it returns `Query is undefined` even when I hit the endpoint with a query param.

example : `http://localhost:3000/api/products?abc=def`

I wanted to get something like an object:

```json
{
   "abc" : "def"
}
```

I am using version 14 of NextJS with TypeScript.

This is not a **"use client"** issue.

Also, the endpoint is working since I am getting all the products in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import { initMongoose } from "@/lib/mongoose";
import Product from "@/models/products";
//import { NextApiRequest } from "next";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
  
  //console.log("Query is ",req.query);
  const searchParams = req.nextUrl.searchParams;
  const abc = searchParams.get('abc');
  console.log("Query is ", abc); 

  await initMongoose();

  return NextResponse.json(await Product.find().exec());
}
```

NextJSv13.4+ switched from using NextAPIRequest to NextRequest.  NextAPIRequest is derived from Node requests whereas NextRequest is derived more directly from Web API requests.  And with the change, the helper methods changed as well.

Comment: Thank You. This work.

Comment: One more question, when i consoled query, it had symbols as keys example: [Symbol(state)], any idea what they mean ?